# How to use Function types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to understand how to use "Function types".

Let's say we have the following:

```
function calSum(val1: number, val2: number): number{
    return val1 * val2;
}
console.log(calSum(10,20)); //prints 200
```

Now let's say we have:

```
let calc: (value1: number, value2: number) => number;
```

if I do the following:

```
calc(10,20);
```

I would expect to see 200, however I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: calFuncType is not a function
```

I would like to understand why this is, and how to use this type?

Comment: Because you're setting a type for `calc` (`foo: type`), not assigning a value (`foo = value`).

Comment: ahh I get what you mean now! i am not assigning the function to the function type variable @jonrsharpe

Comment: Shouldn't be it `let calc = (value1: number, value2: number) => value1 * value2`?

Comment: You're not actually creating a function. You're defining a type. I don't really know how else to put it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
let calc: (value1: number, value2: number) => number;
```

Compiles into:

```
let calc;
```

That is, you only declared a variable with a name, but you haven't assign a value to it.

This is how to assign a value to it:

```
let calc: (value1: number, value2: number) => number = function(val1: number, val2: number): number{
    return val1 * val2;
}
```

The compiler can infer types, so this should be enough:

```
let calc = function(val1: number, val2: number): number{
    return val1 * val2;
}
```

Or, using arrow functions:

```
let calc = (val1: number, val2: number) => val1 * val2;
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I understood it. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `calSum` is a concrete implementation of your function, while `calc` is a variable that has not been assigned to anything yet, so it is `undefined`. You have specified the type of value that `calc` can hold, but you haven't actually given it a value yet.

I think what you might be looking for is how to define an interface for a function, and then implementing that interface. For example:

```
interface CalcFunction {
  (value1: number, value2: number): number;
}

let multiply: CalcFunction = (a, b) => a * b;
let add: CalcFunction = (a, b) => a + b;

let product: number = multiply(3, 5);
let sum: number = add(3, 5);

console.log(product); // 15
console.log(sum); // 8
```

TypeScript will know that both `multiply` and `add` take two `number` arguments and return a `number` because they both explicitly implement the `CalcFunction` interface.

Then, for example, you could do something like this:

```
let calculate = (calc: CalcFunction, a: number, b: number): number => {
  return calc(a, b);
}
```